How to send a request to DNS server through Postman?
So this might be a very stupid question, but I tried to search the internet about how to communicate with the DNS server, means that how to send the request and in what form does the DNS server sends the response back, but I was not able to replicate anything in Postman.
I tried using port 443 and 53, but no response back. I tried with the server 8.8.8.8

Not straight request but you can do work around. https://dns.google/resolve?name=example.com&type=A

@DivyangDesai Why can't we send a straight request? How else does my laptop communicate with the DNS then?

Search difference between http request and tcp/udp request. Postman is to send mostly http request...
